# Resizing a vector of vectors

Tags: c++, vector, operator-precedence, comma-operator

Below is chunk of code for resizing a vector of vectors. The output produced for size of each row is printed 0? Why is this happening even though i resized each row to W;

```
int main() {
    int H,W,i;
    cin >> H,W; // H=3,W=5;
    vector<vector<int> >v;
    v.resize(H);

    for(i=0;i<H;i++)
        v[i].resize(W);

    cout << v[1].size(); // Output is printed 0 
}
```

Comment: `cin >> H,W` isn't doing what you think it is

Comment: `cin >> H,W; // H=3,W=5;` This comment is incorrect, and you could have easily verified it yourself by just printing out `H` and `W`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic - what does the debugger tell you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cin >> H,W;` doesn't do what you expect. According to the [C++ Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), it's the same as `(cin >> H), W;`, the 2nd expression `W` does nothing in fact, so `W` is not initialized at all. Any usage of it would lead to [undefined behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Change it to `cin >> H >> W;`.

BTW: Change `cout << v[1].size();` to `cout << v[i].size();`.